# Fetch first row as Headers from one csv and values from other csv

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have two csv's. First csv has only 1 row which is headers. 2nd csv has values.
I want to create the dataframe which has headers from row1 from csv1 and values from all rows within csv 2. Both the csv's has same number of fields starting from _c0 till _c1000 (has about 1000 columns). Columns types can be different within each csv but column names and number of columns will be same. Below is the example snip. I am using databricks (pyspark). Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can impose the schema resulted from reading the first file on reading the second file:

```
df1 = spark.read.option('header', True).csv('<path to the file with header>')
df2 = spark.read.schema(df1.schema).csv('<path to the file without header>')
```

Comment: yeah, that works for creating just one df, How do I use the headers from this first df and values from another?

Comment: @user1403789 Sorry didn't read the question completely. I've refined my answer.

Comment: no, this is not working. It still is showing _c0....._c1000 as column name in df2

Comment: @user1403789 shouldn't have used `schema` as an option. Fixed the code.

Comment: IS there way to use just the column names but not column datatypes from df1? While df1 is all column name and they are all string. when used them as schema in df2, they all inherit strings, but in actual they have different datatypes.

Comment: Do you want the datatypes to be specific or a generic type ike `StringType`?